# PHP/MySQL: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: php, mysql, null, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm relatively new to (My)SQL and have been bashing my keyboard with my head for over two days now. I just can't seem to solve the problem. I have a database that holds three tables: *items*, *coords*, and *price*. The table items has a non-mandatory 1-to-many relationship with price, and a mandatory 1:1 relationship with coords. Whenever I try to update all three of them, I get this error:

"Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
(`items`.`items`, CONSTRAINT `fk_items_coords1` FOREIGN KEY (`coords_idCoords`) REFERENCES `coords` (`idCoords`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

"

I've tried everything I could find and think of: changing the order of insertion, changing the relationships itself, adding manually first (I know this is a must) etc. etc. I've also tried changing them both to mandatory for a moment, as I noticed this problem doesn't occur at the insertion of the foreign key of price. I found out it just inserts a null value, however. It probably holds a really easy solution, but I just can't get my head around it.

[Here is my PHP](http://pastebin.com/nxmXTZjm) and [here is my SQL](http://pastebin.com/4SVtVRGk).

I'm well aware that the PHP is sloppy (especially the two seperate queries), but I'll get around to that once I've fixed this. I hope I've provided you with enough information. If there's anything else you need, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is pretty straightforward. You are trying to insert some `coord` into `items` where coord with such ID does not exist.

Double check data you are trying to insert...

Comment: There is data present in both coords as price, however.

Comment: Yes, but the point is wrong key value being inserted into `items`. How about that?

Comment: So how would you suggest fixing this? Sorry, I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: Make yourself up a file with some sql insert statements.  That will help narrow down the problem to a specific statement.  Consider also rebuilding your schema without the constraints and see exactly what is being inserted.

Comment: I have tried inserting by ignoring the foreign keys, and all is being inserted, including two NULL values where price_idPrice and coords_idCoords are supposed to be. Let me create a file, then.